# How to run testcafe tests in teamcity CI?

Tags: reactjs, automation, continuous-integration, teamcity, testcafe

I want to run Testcafe E2E tests in teacity CI/CD server. Can someone please help me to understand how can we use testcafe/testcafe docker image in teamcity to run the tests?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you refer to the following topics where you can find information on how to make it work:

Here is an article that describes how to [integrate TestCafe with TeamCity](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/continuous-integration/teamcity.html).
Please also take a look at the following article: [Use TestCafe Docker Image](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/use-testcafe-docker-image.html).

Feel free to contact us if you need assistance with combining these tools.

**UPDATED:**

TeamCity goes along with the [Docker Wrapper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/docker-wrapper.html) extension for Command Line Build Step. It provides an easy way to run a custom script inside a docker container.

However, you need to take into account the following specifics:

- The TestCafe Docker image comes with a special [script](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/docker/testcafe-docker.sh) that prepares the container environment by starting services like Xvfb and DBus. It is located in `/opt/testcafe/bin/testcafe-docker.sh`. The TeamCity wrapper overrides the entrypoint of the docker images and prevents execution of this script. It means that `/opt/testcafe/bin/testcafe-docker.sh` should be used instead of `testcafe` to run your test with Docker and TeamCity:

```sh
/opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh chromium test/e2e/**/* -r teamcity
```

- It's better to use [headless mode](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/browsers.html#test-in-headless-mode) when testing in Docker containers, since this mode is specially designed for such environments.
- If you don't use the headless mode in Chrome for some reason, you can encounter the following error: **ERROR: Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.** Likely, it is caused by the following Chrome's bug: [TMPDIR too long](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=469065). In order to solve this problem, you need to manually set an environment variable before starting TestCafe:

```sh
export TMPDIR=/tmp
```

Configured Build Step may look like:

[image]

This configuration implies that you are using TestCafe with [TeamCity TestCafe reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-teamcity) installed as local packages. Ensure that the node_modules directory with TestCafe and plugins is a subdirectory of the test project root directory. TeamCity Docker Wrapper will mount the working directory inside the container.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please summarize the contents of the links, and only provide links for further reference.

Comment: I tried to use docker image testcafe/testcafe and running the command :
-v $PWD:/automation -w /automation -i testcafe/testcafe 'chromium --no-sandbox' ./automation/**/*.ts --proxy-bypass *.mydevurl.com --proxy proxyname.com:port

Comment: It is actually pulling the image but not running the tests in teamcity

Comment: Also I tried to set up the steps like this 
 but getting error(https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/use-testcafe-docker-image.html)
_ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure._